# Using any to check existence of element in array inside hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to check if an element (array) of a hash contains a specific item by using `any`. Because my arrays can get very large it seemed `any` was the most efficient way as it returns true as soon as the item is found. The problem is that CLI returns:

> Type of arg 1 to List::Util::any must be block or sub {} (not array
>   dereference) at ...

The line is (changed to a fictitious example) reproduced below. I am trying to see if `id` of `item2` is inside `field` of `item1` in the fictitious example below.

```
unless(any(@{$hash{$item1}{field}}) eq $hash{$item2}{id}) {
  # Do magic.
}
```

What am I doing wrong? As [`any`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#any) is part of `List::Util`, I have loaded that module at the top.

```
use List::Util qw(any);
```

Comment: how large is very large?  any is much much slower than grep.  have you actually timed how long it takes with grep?

Comment: @ysth The amount can run into the hundred thousands.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip: Why did you delete your answer? It seems fine to me.

Comment: @BramVanroy and what percentage of the time do you expect to find the element you are looking for?

Comment: @ysth That's hard to say because I'm working with linguistic data. I assume you are getting at the following, that if I don't expect the result to be found often, grep will be faster because the whole array has to be looked through any way?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a hash instead of an array?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Not really. The outermost hash itself will grow quite big, so I thought to limit memory usage I wouldn't construct objects that aren't necessary and I (wrongly?) assumed that a hash (x100.000s) would be significantly more memory consuming than arrays. Am I wrong?

Comment: In general, hashes use more memory than arrays, but it's not significant enough to worry about in most cases. A hash with 100,000 keys would be on the order of 10 MB, which is not very much. And a hash of 100,000 words of average English text would actually be significantly smaller than the corresponding array because the array would contain many, many duplicates. Unless you need the elements to be ordered or need to keep duplicates, use a hash; lookups will be much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the function:

```
use List::Util qw(any);
```

UPDATE:  As noted, the 1st arg to `any` should be a block of code.   In this case, compare the hash value to $_, which is assigned to each value in your array until the condition is true.

```
unless(any { $_ eq $hash{$item2}{id} } @{$hash{$item1}{field}}) {
```

Comment: @BramVanroy: `any { $hash{$item2}{id} } @{$hash{$item1}{field}})` ***will not work***. It simply returns a *true* value if the value of `$hash{$item2}{id}` is *true*, i.e. it exists and is defined and is not `0` or `"0"` or the null string. You *must* set `$_` for the result of the block to depend on the list of values that you are testing, otherwise your code will just test the same, unrelated value `$hash{$item2}{id}` over and over again.